# Not sure how this recursion works

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

```
class Solution: 
    def findDuplicateSubtrees(self, root):
        self.res = []
        self.dic = {}
        self.dfs(root)
        return self.res

    def dfs(self, root):
        if not root: return '#'
        tree = self.dfs(root.left) + self.dfs(root.right) + str(root.val)

        if tree in self.dic and self.dic[tree] == 1:
            self.res.append(root)
        self.dic[tree] = self.dic.get(tree, 0) + 1

        return tree
```

This is a solution for getting all duplicate subtrees given a binary tree.
I am not sure what `tree = self.dfs(root.left) + self.dfs(root.right) + str(root.val)` is trying to give.

I know it's trying to do a postorder traversal, but how does this part actually work?

It would be great if anyone can follow through this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the variable `tree` can be regarded as an encoding string for each subtree. And we use a global dict `self.dic` to memorize those encoded strings.

An examples:

```
     A
  B      C
D   D  E   B
          D  D
```

In level order, the binary tree can be descripted as `[[A], [B, C], [D, D, E, B], [#, #, #, #, #, #, D, D]]`, so we have at least two duplicate subtrees as `[[B], [D, D]]` and `[D]`
Follow the code, we have

```
dfs(A)
  dfs(B)
    dfs(D) *save ##D, return ##D
    dfs(D) *find ##D, get one subtree, return ##D
  *save ##D##DB, return ##D##DB
  dfs(C)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is best untangled from bottom up.

- A non-node (a daughter of a leaf node) will return `"#"`.
- A leaf with value `1` would return `"##1"` (as it has two non-node children).
- A node `3` with two leaf daughters `1` and `2` would return `##1##23`. `"##1"` is the `dfs` of the left daughter, `"##2"` is the `dfs` of the right daughter, and `"3"` is the stringified current node's value.

In this way, assuming there's no node with value `23` and another with empty string value, you can see that if two different nodes produce `##1##23`, they are a duplicate subtree. It would be much more robust if there were some additional separators employed (e.g. a semicolon at the end of that line would produce `"##1;##2;3;`), which would be sufficient to make it a bit more readable and less ambiguous. Even safer (but slower) if done with lists.